# Adding child fragments in a separate thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-fragments

I'm having an issue with adding a child fragment to another fragment in my android app.

In the parent fragment I have something like this:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(blah) {
        Thread initializeStateThread = new Thead() {
            public void run() {
                // Make some requests to get some data that determines
                // which child fragment to display
                state = // Some state that corresponds to a child frag

                // Method that set's the child fragment based on |state|
                setChildFragment(state);
            }
        } 
        initializeStateThread.start()

        // Do a bunch of other stuff

        return view;
    }

    setChildFragment(State state) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (mState) {
            case CASE_1:
                fragment = new DriverFindSpotFragment();
                break;
            case CASE_2:
                fragment = new DriverNavigationFragment();
                break;
            case CASE_3:
                fragment = new DriverArriveSpotFragment();
                break;
        }

        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Ovverride
        public void run() {
            getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
               replace(R.id.driver_fragment_container, fragment).commit();
        };
    }
```

However, this only works about 50% of the time. The other 50% of the time the child fragment just doesn't show up (there isn't an error or anything). I think the problem is related to the fact that I'm attempting to add a child fragment after the parent's view is returned form onCreateView.

I've noticed that if I force the main thread to sleep for a second or two, the issue goes away (I assume because the child fragment gets set before the view is returned in that case).

Has anyone ever run into a similar issue? Or can anyone confirm my theory as to why this issue is happening?

Comment: Why you are replace fragment in thread any special purpose?

Comment: I don't know which child fragment I want to set until after the thread finishes requesting some data from my server; thus I have to do it after I make those (blocking) requests

Comment: Not sure but it seems problem with replacement in thread , you can replace after your server response for state

Answer (score 0):

You can try as following method define it in fragment and replace with position/state

```
public void displayView(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new FormFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new HomeFragment();
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();
        if (position != 0)
            // transaction.addToBackStack("back");
            transaction.replace(R.id.main_ll_container, fragment).commit();
    } else {
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that you've just abstracted my logic into a separate method -- I'm not sure how that will fix the problem?

Comment: i'm asking for purposes of runnable in replacement of fragment?

Comment: The fragment cannot be replaced until after the blocking requests finish. Thus, I cannot do the fragment replacement directly in the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding your Fragment transaction in Main thread.

**Like this :**

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.driver_fragment_container, fragment).commit();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I can't really do that though, because I don't know which fragment to set until after I wait to receive the data that the thread is requesting. If I did all of that in the main thread I would be blocking the main thread, which is obviously undesirable

Comment: Oh and actually I'm already running this on the UI thread -- it's still not working. I'll update my pseudo code

Comment: I understood. I thinks this code will meet your purpose. Just try it by replacing your fragment transaction line with my code

Comment: you may need to make your fragment final also

Comment: No I've already tried using runOnUiThread, and it did not work

Comment: then try your threading call in on start() or onResume(). remove code from onCreateView()

Answer (score 0):

After reading the comments and other answers, I am not sure what and where is the actual problem.

Instead of:

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     @Ovverride
        public void run() {
     }
});
```

Use:

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
     @Ovverride
        public void run() {
     }
});
```

This is just a wild guess, most probably it will work.